# Implementing a Laravel 4 Pivot Table using Eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, many-to-many, eloquent

I've got the following structure in my database:

-shared_resources table
-tags table
-shared_resource_tag table

There is a many to many relationship between shared_resources and tags. When I am creating a shared_resource I do the following:

1. Add the shared_resource to the shared_resources table
2. Add the tags to the tags table
3. Add the shared_resource_id and the tag_id to the shared_resource_tag table

I can manage to get through steps 1 and 2 but for some reason I am unable to make any entries to the `pivot table`. I don't know why. I set up the relationships in my `models` accordingly:

`SharedResource`:

```
class SharedResource extends Eloquent{
    public function tags(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('Tag');
    }
}
```

`Tag`:

```
class Tag extends Eloquent{
    public function sharedResources(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('SharedResource');
    }
}
```

Then when I am creating the entries I do this:

```
        $tags = Array();
        $tags = explode(',', Input::get('tags'));
        foreach($tags as $tag){
            $newTag = new Tag;
            $newTag->name = $tag;
            $newTag->save();
        }

        //Pivot table entry
        $resource->tags()->sync($tags);

        $resource->save();
```

The code above runs into an error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'shared_resource_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select `tag_id` from `shared_resource_tag` where `shared_resource_id` is null)
```

I'm very confused as to whats going on, I understood that `Eloquent` made implementing these n:n relationships easy.

Comment: Not really, otherwise I don't think I would have taken the time to type the question out...

Comment: So do you have `shared_resource_id` field on that table..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sync()` method will need the id's of the tags, and not the string names which you are giving it. You can try something like:

```
$tags = Array();
$tagIds = Array();
$tags = explode(',', Input::get('tags'));
foreach($tags as $tag){
    $newTag = new Tag;
    $newTag->name = $tag;
    $newTag->save();
    $tagIds[] = $newTag->id;
}

//Pivot table entry
$resource->tags()->sync($tagIds);

$resource->save();
```

You can find more info [here](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#inserting-related-models) under `Using Sync To Attach Many To Many Models`

Comment: I see what your saying @Chris G, I'm still getting the error though regarding  `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'shared_resource_id`, I tried saving the resource before making the pivot entries but that did not work

Comment: @Javacadabra - you might have to add the column names that you are joining in: `return $this->belongsToMany('SharedResource');`. From the manual: `return $this->belongsToMany('Role', 'user_roles', 'user_id', 'foo_id');` it looks like Laravel is trying to make a connection that isn't there (given the missing column), so you'll have to force them in your model to overwrite the default actions.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $tags = explode(',', Input::get('tags'));
    // Create or add tags
    $tagIds = array();

    if ( $tags )
    {
        $found = $this->tag->findOrCreate( $tags );
        foreach ( $found as $tag )
        {
            $tagIds[ ] = $tag->id;
        }
    }

    // Assign set tags to model
    $model->tags()->sync( $tagIds );
```